# Возможна ли распаковка пары и кортежа в уже созданные переменные

Tags: c++, c++23

Есть функция, которая возвращает пару или кортеж. Результат её вызова нужно сохранить в уже созданные ранее переменные. Можно ли это сделать не создавая промежуточных объектов?

```
// Функция возвращает пару. 
std::pair<int, int> Foo() { return { 1, 2 }; }

...

// Распаковка пары в новые переменные.
auto [one, two] = Foo();
member_one_ = one; // Затем записываем результат в уже существующие переменные. 
member_two_ = two;
```

В этом примере приходится создавать ненужные переменные one и two, которые по сути не нужны. Вместо этого хотелось бы видеть что-то подобное.

```
// Записываем возвращаемые значения сразу в необходимые переменные. 
[ member_one, member_two ] = Foo();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Structured binding не может распаковывать в существующие переменные.

Кроме того, обратите внимание, что он создает не несколько отдельных переменных, а одну - безымянную (имена в квадратных скобках ссылаются на ее поля). Хотя в вашем случае это ничего не меняет.

---

Решение такое: `std::tie(member_one, member_two) = Foo();`. Работает даже в С++11.

Comment: Если автор имел ввиду что то другое, то извеняюсь, но по моему это то что он хотел.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Хмм, что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: не знаю, потому что не уверен, что правильно понимаю смысл и применимость вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо. Это именно то что было нужно.